# Make a program to solve this question using python:

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, combinations, permutation

Find the number of 6 digit numbers such that each digit appears atleast twice

I tried the below code but it doesn't work:

```
count = 0
for n in range(10**5,(10**6)-1):
    n = str(n).split()
    
for i in range(len(n)):
    
    n[i] = int(n[i])
    if n.count(i) >= 2:
        
        
        count+=1
print(count)
```

The original question is of Permutation and Combinations but I want to solve this using python...

Comment: what "doesn't work"? be specific.

Comment: `str(n).split()` won't split the number into a list of digits, since there's no delimiter between the digits.

Comment: Why do you think you need to split it? You can loop over a string and it will process the characters.

Comment: The `for i` loop needs to be inside the `for n` loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Comment: I recommend starting out by `import logging` followed by `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`, and inserting a few `logging.debug('n=%s', n)` and the like throughout the program. You might find out you're just spinning your wheels.

Comment: I solved it using permutations and combinations and got 15 * 9 * 9 * 8 = 9720.  Is that close?

Comment: @Frank Yellin the answer is 11754

Comment: Oh sorry .  I misread as every character appears exactly twice.  Sorry.  I forgot to include the 3/3s and the 4/2s.

Comment: @FrankYellin you missed the 9 6s as well. 2/2/2s - 9 * 9 * 8 * 15 = 9720, 3/3s - 9 * 9 * 10 = 810, 4/2s - 9 * 9 * 15 = 1215, 6s = 9. The total turns out to be `11754`

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the mistakes in your code -

1. The range needs to be `range(10**5, 10**6)` to cover all 6 digit numbers
2. `str(n).split()` won't split the `n` into a list of characters since there is no delimiter between the string representation of the number. You can use `[letter for letter in str(n)]` instead.
3. You want to run the second loop for each of the numbers in the first loop, so the second loop needs to be inside the first loop.
4. Within the second loop, you are increasing the `count` if one of the digits occurs more than twice in the number, so you might end up increasing the count multiple times for a single number. e.g. for `112233` you would end up increasing the `count` by 3 instead of just 1.

here's a simplified code which does what you want in a similar format -

```
count = 0
for n in range(10**5, 10**6):
    n = [letter for letter in str(n)]
    count += 1
    for letter in n:
        if n.count(letter) < 2:    
            count -= 1
            break

print(count)
```

outputs -

```
11754
```

You can use `all()` function along with list comprehension to simplify the code -

```
count = 0
for n in range(10**5, 10**6):
    n = [letter for letter in str(n)]
    count += all(n.count(letter) >= 2 for letter in n)
```

Comment: Thankyou@ Max Miller

Comment: @PriyanshuPandey please consider [accepting/upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
answers = []
count = 0
my_dict = {}
digits = '0123456789'
for n in range(10**5, (10**6)-1):
    my_dict = {}
    ns = str(n)
    for m in ns:
        if m in digits:
            my_dict[m] = ns.count(m)
    if my_dict[min(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)] > 1:
        count += 1
        answers.append(ns)
print(count)
```

Here is an alternative way. It gets the correct number.